# What is this fish disease?

Tags: health, aquarium, fish, diseases

I had 4 platies and 5 danios but there are only 1 platy and 4 danios left. mysteriously, they die in the same manner, like sinking to the bottom of the tank and resting there. I was wondering if they had the same disease that caused them to die that way, and now I have another platy that is looking like it is going to die soon, just like the other fishes die as I stated just now.

Or perhaps they just died of old age? I don't know. My platy shown in the image below is about 2 years old.

***The Platy below in the image has died***

[image]

Comment: please edit in the readings of your latest water test ammonia-nitrite-ph,is your tank properly cycled and how large is the tank what type of filtration do you have what number of fish do you have in your tank,for how long did your fish live days?months?years?.the water test is the most important information to answer your question.

Comment: Hi thank you for ur answer, as I am a starter at  keeping fish, I don't test the water for ammonia and nitrate pH.

Comment: however, I think I am going to buy a test kit soon

Comment: you need to read this to be sure your fish will survive https://www.fishlore.com/NitrogenCycle.htm sadly most petshops fail to give this information to you when you buy  the tank and fish to start a new hobby.

Comment: thank you, I will read it